# jQuery: Rearranging Elements Without Repeating

Tags: jquery, each, dom-manipulation, insertafter

Let's say you have HTML like this:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    <div class="top">top</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    <div class="top">top</div>
</div>
```

and you want to move `.top` above `.bottom` in each `.section` with jQuery.

I'm trying to do this with:

```
$('.section').each(function (i, obj) {
    $('.bottom').insertAfter('.top');
});
```

But this is causing "bottom" to repeat itself four times in each section.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TLejL/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `$(this)` reference inside the `.each()` function,

```
$('.section').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(this).find('.bottom').insertAfter($(this).find('.top'));
});
```

or

```
$('.top').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.section').prepend($(this));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TLejL/2/)

Comment: that did it!  is this the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: @ErikBerger the first one is just an imitation of your code, but the second one would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the top & bottom elements within the current `section`

```
$('.section .top').after(function (i, obj) {
    return $(this).prev()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qyR2t/)